# Where is most appropriate for Cloudfoundry server admin questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252730/nats-error-unresponsive-client-detected-connection-dropped) is probably a server administration question than a development one.  Would ServerFault be more appropriate (as I have suggested to the OP), given the current lack of any kind of cloud.stackexchange.com?

If there is a more appropriate location than stackoverflow.com, Cloud Foundry should get a heads-up, as they currently [push](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/getinvolved) *all* questions to either Twitter or the main SO site.  Maybe them adding a second link to a *cloudfoundry* tag on ServerFault (or wherever is more appropriate) would be advisable.

Answer (score 1):

I would post such a question on Server Fault as you already suggest. From their [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions):

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a **professional capacity**.
>
> If your question is about…
>
> - Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization
> - Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
> - Network routing, switches, and firewalls
> - Operations, maintenance, and monitoring